# Error in displaying the List of programs from database

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, linq, model-view-controller

Here i am trying to show the list of programs from database in my list.cshtml.  I am not able to get the list of programs.

Suggest me if there is any wrong in code. I am facing issue in `cacheUtilities` as `ArgumentNullException`. someone help me with the code issue to get the list of programs from database.

**Controller Code**

```
    [HttpGet]
    [Authorize(Roles = "Affiliate")]
    public ActionResult GetTrainingPrograms(int? affiliateId, string searchStr, bool? active, string sort, int? start, int? limit)
    {
        int affId = UserData.AffiliateID;
        if (affiliateId != null && affiliateId.Value > 0)
        {
            affId = affiliateId.Value;
        }

        string searchStrLower = string.Empty;
        string queryStr = String.Concat(affId);
        // The start point in the list of Training Programs
        if (start != null)
        {
            queryStr = String.Concat(queryStr, "-", start.Value);
        }
        // To find Active or Inactive at the Current Time
        if (active != null)
        {
            queryStr = String.Concat(queryStr, "-", active);
        }
        // Sort the List of Data
        if (sort == null)
        {
            sort = "trainingProgramName";

        }
        queryStr = String.Concat(queryStr, "-", sort);
        // limit on the page to Display
        if (limit != null)
        {
            queryStr = String.Concat(queryStr, "-", limit.Value);
        }
        //The keywords used to find a Training Program
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchStr))
        {
            searchStrLower = searchStr.ToLower();
            queryStr = String.Concat(queryStr, "-", searchStrLower);
        }

        logger.Debug("trainingProgramListKey: " + queryStr);

        TrainingProgramList reloadData = CacheUtilities.Instance.GetTrainingProgramList(affiliateId);
        logger.Debug("reloadData: " + reloadData + ", affId: " + affId + ", queryStr: " + queryStr);
        string trainingProgramCacheKey = CbConstants.TrainingProgramCacheKey + queryStr;

        TrainingProgramList trainingProgramList = null;

        int totalCount = 0;
        // Checks the List is null or not to Display
        if (trainingProgramList != null)
        {
            logger.Debug("Cache miss for TrainingProgram list: " + trainingProgramCacheKey);

            trainingProgramList = new TrainingProgramList();
            trainingProgramList.AffiliateID = affId;
            totalCount = TrainingProgramRepository.Instance.GetTrainingProgramsCount(affId, searchStrLower, active);
            trainingProgramList.Entries = TrainingProgramRepository.Instance.GetTrainingPrograms(affId, searchStrLower, active, sort, start, limit);

            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(trainingProgramCacheKey, trainingProgramList, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, CbConstants.CacheSlidingExpirationOneDay);
        }


        CbJsonResponse response = new CbJsonResponse();
        response.Data.Add(trainingProgramList);
        response.Status = "success";
        response.Meta.Add("total", Convert.ToString(totalCount));

        return Json(response, "application/json", System.Text.Encoding.UTF8, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

}

**Repository Code:**

```
    public List<TrainingProgramListEntry> GetTrainingPrograms(int affiliateId, string searchStr, bool? active, string sort, int? start, int? limit)
    {
        using (var ctx = new CrossfitPortalEntities())
        {
            ctx.Database.Log = s => System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(s);

            // Don't need proxies when explicitly loading.
            ctx.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false;

            var query = ctx.TrainingPrograms.Where(m => m.AffiliateID == affiliateId);

            //The keywords used to find a Training Program
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(searchStr))
            {
                query = query.Where(m => m.Name.ToLower().Contains(searchStr));
            }

            if (active != null)
            {

            }
            // The property on which to sort this list.
            if (sort != null)
            {
                switch (sort)
                {
                    case "TrainingProgram Name":
                        query = query.OrderBy(m => m.Name);
                        break;
                }
            }
            //The number of Training Programs to display on this page.
            if (limit != null)
            {
                logger.Debug("TrainingProgram query limit: " + limit.Value);
            }

            var entries = query.Select(m => new TrainingProgramListEntry
            {
                Name = m.Name,
                ColorCode = m.ColorCode,
       // The start point in the list of Training Programs
            }).Skip((start != null) ? start.Value : 0).Take((limit != null) ? limit.Value : 10).ToList();

            return entries;
        }
    }
```

**CacheUtilites Code:**

```
    public TrainingProgramList GetTrainingProgramList(int? affiliateID)
    {

        string trainingProgramCacheKey = CbConstants.TrainingProgramCacheKey + affiliateID;
        TrainingProgramList trainingprogram = (TrainingProgramList)HttpRuntime.Cache[trainingProgramCacheKey];
        if (trainingprogram != null)
        {
            logger.Debug("Cache hit for AffProfile Entity: " + trainingProgramCacheKey);
        }
        else
        {
            logger.Debug("Cache miss for AffProfile Entity: " + trainingProgramCacheKey);
             trainingprogram = TrainingProgramRepository.Instance.GetTrainingPrograms(AffiliateID);


            HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(trainingProgramCacheKey, trainingprogram, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, CbConstants.CacheSlidingExpirationTwoHours);
        }

        return trainingprogram;
    }
```

Comment: Fire up your debugger, isolate the part that is wrong and post it here. You have way too much code there. You expect us to sift through it and brain-debug it for you?

Comment: i mentioned the problem as i am facing in repository.

Comment: On which line do you encounter the exception?

Comment: Also, that isn´t quite the way to use MVC.. cacheutilities code is also controller code and should be placed there, maybe in another class but still.. and you have logic in the repository code.. the purpose of MVC is to separate the model, view and controller codes to make it easier to understand the code

Comment: in cacheutilities code ->  HttpRuntime.Cache.Insert(trainingProgramCacheKey, trainingprogram, null, Cache.NoAbsoluteExpiration, CbConstants.CacheSlidingExpirationTwoHours);

Comment: Thank you i have resolved the issue.